# How to programmatically enable wi-fi on android device in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-wifi

I was need to enable and disable programmatically wi-fi on my Android device in Delphi.

Comment: Why exactly Delphi? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have been programming in Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample can solve this issue:

```
procedure TForm1.btWiFiEnableClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  WiFIServiceNative: JWifiManager;
begin
  // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getWifiState()
  // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_DISABLED
  WiFIServiceNative := TJWifiManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE));
  if Assigned(WiFIServiceNative) then begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Has Wifi manager');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Wifi state is ' + IntToStr(WiFIServiceNative.getWifiState));

    // if WiFIServiceNative.getWifiState = TJWifiManager.JavaClass.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED then
    if WiFIServiceNative.getWifiState < 2 then // WIFI_STATE_DISABLING or WIFI_STATE_DISABLED
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Try to Wi-Fi on:');
      if WiFIServiceNative.setWifiEnabled(true) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' - ' + IntToStr(TJWifiManager.JavaClass.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) + ' OK')
      else
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' - FAIL');
    end else begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Try to Wi-Fi off:');
      if WiFIServiceNative.setWifiEnabled(false) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' - ' + IntToStr(TJWifiManager.JavaClass.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED) + ' OK')
      else
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' - FAIL');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It needs to use the following permissions:

```
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```